# Why is Python giving the error: "TypeError: expected string or buffer" when using re?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, typeerror

I don't know what minor mistake I am making, but I feel there is a simple solution here that I am not getting.  From a log file, I am trying to read only the lines that end in "start".  There is a lot of information on each line, so I have simplified the re to: 
"(.*)start$"     which I believe is correct.
An example of a string is:

`05/06/2013 12:06:58 AM | null | com.skldfjs : start`

```
import pandas as pd
s=pd.read_csv('Log_file.csv')
s
import re
items=re.findall("(.*)start$",s,re.MULTILINE)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
<b>TypeError: expected string or buffer</b>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or why this is happening?
Thank you!
Kelsey

Comment: I ultimately want to get obtain the start time and end time of a line to compute the elapsed time that it takes to complete at task. Thus, I am trying to first receive the lines that have the word "start" in them, and do the same for lines that have the word "end" in them.  Thus I was using 're.findall' but I am getting an error.  I then want to match the end and start times for a task, subtract them, and get time elapsed on one csv file.   However, I can't move on to the next steps until this error gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening due to pandas.read_csv() is returning a non string object, instead a excel like file.

Since I have never used pandas, cannot give more information. However, if there is no absolute need for pandas, you could try to read the file as a plain text file and then use re.findall() to parse it.

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    content = f.read()

regex = r"(.*)start$"
items = re.findall(regex, content, re.MULTILINE)
```